# check if form input is equal to specific text if so perform calculation and print in another input field

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to be able to check two input field values (return and stakePlaced) e.g. 100 and 20

if the result field = win, then perform calculation: return (minus - ) stakePlaced and then display the result in another field called profit.

PHP is being used to pull data from table --- ignore the PHP code.

**HTML**

```
<div class="form-group">
  <label for="stakePlaced">Stake Placed</label>
  <input type="text" class="form-control mb-2" placeholder="stakePlaced" name="stakePlaced" value="<?php echo $stakePlaced ?>">
</div>

<div class="form-group">
  <label for="result">Result</label>
  <input type="text" class="form-control mb-2" placeholder="result" name="result" id="result" onchange="calcula" value="<?php echo $result ?>">
</div>

<div class="form-group">
  <label for="return">Return</label>
  <input type="text" class="form-control mb-2" placeholder="return" name="return" id="return" value="<?php echo $return ?>">
</div>

<div class="form-group">
  <label for="return">Profit</label>
  <input type="text" class="form-control mb-2" placeholder="profit" name="profit" id="profit" value="<?php echo $profit ?>">
</div>
```

**JS**

```
  function calcula(){
    $(document).ready(function(){
      $("#result").keyup(function(){
        if (this.value == "Win"){
          var vreturn = document.getElementById('return').value;
          var stake = document.getElementById('stakePlaced').value; 
          var result = parseFloat(vreturn)-parseFloat(stake);

          var secresult = result.toFixed(2);

          document.getElementById('profit').value = secresult;
       }
    });
});
 window.onload = calcula;
```

Comment: return and profit fields have no IDs.

Comment: Thanks, I  added both ID's, still not working.

Comment: Please explain what "not working" means. What error are you getting? is the result/calculation wrong? is it not calculating at all?

Comment: thanks for the input, it is now working with the help from Louys Patrice Bessette

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your math is unclear... I don't know how the value could be `Win` when dealing with numeric values... But that may be something out of scope.

To get the input values by the `name` (since there is no `id`), you can use [attribute selectors](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors).

See below... Type "Win" in the "Result" field (second). It will output "0.00" in the "Profit" field (last).

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#result").keyup(function(){
    if (this.value == "Win"){
      console.log("Win!");
      var vreturn = $("[name='return']").val();
      var stake = $("[name='stakePlaced']").val(); 
      var result = parseFloat(vreturn)-parseFloat(stake);

      var secresult = result.toFixed(2);

      $("[name='profit']").val(secresult);
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="form-group">
  <label for="stakePlaced">Stake Placed</label>
  <input type="text" class="form-control mb-2" placeholder="stakePlaced" name="stakePlaced" value="20">
</div>

<div class="form-group">
  <label for="result">Result</label>
  <input type="text" class="form-control mb-2" placeholder="result" name="result" id="result" value="100">
</div>

<div class="form-group">
  <label for="return">Return</label>
  <input type="text" class="form-control mb-2" placeholder="return" name="return" value="20">
</div>

<div class="form-group">
  <label for="return">Profit</label>
  <input type="text" class="form-control mb-2" placeholder="profit" name="profit" value="30">
</div>
```

And you don't need to have a `$(document).ready(function(){` in a named function which runs at `window.onload`... ;)

Comment: really appreciate the help, its not working :) thanks very much.